# Intellij idea apache-tomcat rewrite valve config

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

How to config the apache tomcat rewrite valve in IntelliJ idea?

I need to add `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />` in my tomcat `server.xml` to enable the rewrite rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}              ^/page/article/.*\.html
RewriteRule /page/article/(.*)\.html    /page/article.html?artId=$1 [NC,L]
```

in a `rewrite.config` file.

I want to enable this so that I can use the IntelliJ Idea's debug features.

Answer (score 0):

There are two directories in IntelliJ idea Tomcat environment:

1. `~/.IntelliJIdea201*/system/tomcat/Unnamed_webappname/conf`, this directory is used as the `CATALINA_BASE` when the apache-tomcat startup in idea. But if you put your modified `context.xml` or `server.xml` here, each time apache-tomcat in idea restart it will be overwritten. So this directory is **not the answer**.
2. The other directory is `conf` directory in the apache-tomcat directory which the idea used. You should put your modified files in this directory. Each time apache-tomcat restart, it will copy the files from this directory.

So to my question, there are two things to do:

1. Add `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />` to the `context.xml` in the tomcat conf directory.
2. Put the `rewrite.config` in place. There are also two choices, one is put the `rewrite.config` in the conf directory too, the other is put the `rewrite.config` in the `WEB-INF` directory. The last is preferred.

And there is actually **no difference with the configuration without `idea`**. The only thing needs to mention is that don't put these configs into the idea temporary directory.